# Getting the SelectedIndex of a LongListSelector Item

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding

I have a WP8 DataBound app with an `ItemViewModel` bound to a `LongListSelector`.

Quite simply, when the user taps on an item in the list, I need to retrieve the *index number* of the item selected for future use. (0 is first in the list, 1 is second, etc.)

So, just as this might retrieve a certain property of the selected item:

```
string whateverProperty = (MyLongListSelector.SelectedItem as ItemViewModel).WhateverProperty;
```

I need something like this (obviously made up code):

```
int indexNumber = (MyLongListSelector.SelectedItem as ItemViewModel).GetSelectedIndex();
```

I think the `SelectedIndex` property is the thing I need but I can't figure out how retrieve it.

Thank you!

EDIT: SOLVED! The following gets me exactly what I was looking for:

```
 int selectedIndex = App.ViewModel.Items.IndexOf(MainLongListSelector.SelectedItem as ItemViewModel);
```

Comment: This always returns -1 for me. Any idea what could be the problem ?

Comment: Same here .. always returns -1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. You need to use the ItemSource to retrieve the index. It should match your data template index for index.

```
int selectedIndex = selector.ItemsSource.IndexOf(selector.SelectedItem as ItemViewModel);
```

selector references the LongListSelector object sender. Hope this helps!