# LongListSelector SelectedItem is Null

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am playing around with a music player app and have the playlist stored in a List.
This is displayed in a LongListSelector containing a StackPanel with an image and two text blocks:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="playlistItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Height="80" Width="80"  Margin="0,0,10,0" Source="/Assets/stop.png" Tap="removeSong_Tap" />
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

When the user clicks on the image, I want to remove the selected song from the list.
I am using the following code:

```
    private void removeSong_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedIndex = playlistList.ItemsSource.IndexOf(playlistList.SelectedItem as ItemViewModel);

        if (selectedIndex == Data.currentSongNo)
        {
            if (Data.currentSongNo == Data.playList.Count - 1) //last song in the playlist
            {
                MediaPlayer.Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                playNextSong();
            }

            removeSongFromPlaylist(selectedIndex);
        }

    }
```

But every time I click on the image, the SelectedItem comes up as null, meaning the selectedIndex is set to -1

I've also tried using:

```
int selectedIndex = App.ViewModel.Items.IndexOf(playlistList.SelectedItem as ItemViewModel);
```

But this has the same results.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `playlistList.Items` instead of `ItemsSource`

Comment: Thanks, but the code doesn't seem to like that. Plus the problem I have is the playlistList.SelectedItem is null

Comment: Out of interest, I got the original code snippet from here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514074/getting-the-selectedindex-of-a-longlistselector-item

Comment: Try using the SelectionChanged event of the LongListSelector!

Comment: I don't think that would help as I only want the tap event to run when the user taps on the [X] image next to the song title

Comment: The screen currently looks like this:

http://i57.tinypic.com/6ycmxg.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this I'm sure. One simple way I've implemented this is to use a flag that's checked at the start of the SelectionChanged event.

The tap event will fire before the selection_changed event in the tree, so I've set up a Tap event like this:

```
    private void ItemClose_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        isItemCloseTapped = true;
    }
```

Then, as the Selection Changed event fires, I've implemented as follows:

```
private void MusicListSelectChange(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
        Model.MusicItem item = ((LongListSelector)sender).SelectedItem as Model.MusicItem;

        if (item == null)
            return;

        if (isItemCloseTapped )
        {
            CloseInList(item);

            isItemCloseTapped = false;
        }
        //...

        //((LongListSelector)sender).SelectedItem = null;
)
```

Again, this is one way to do it, but it's worked well on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to query the `Selected[Index|Item]` query the `sender` in your Tap event handler.
That will tell you which item the person "selected".

The underlying issue you are having is that when the person taps on the image the item isn't actually selected.